# Html not rendering for lightning out rich text field in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-out

We have implemented knowledge in our org, and generally use an employee community to interface it. However, when not using the community we render the articles in a visualforce page that is essentially a wrapper around the custom lightning component (lightning out) that uses a lightning:record to display the content. Everything works EXCEPT that for some rich text fields the html is not rendered, but all the markup and tags are displayed as plain text instead. If I edit the article and manually add a paragraph with a space in it into the source code and publish it again, it then renders fine.

Why is this happening? And why would adding

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Fix the issue?